# How to populate ComboBox inside ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

Since `ComboBox` is within `CellTemplate` I cannot access it and set its `ItemsSource`.
I have a method in other class to pull data from MySql and assign it to the class properties. It works perfect in `ComboBox` outside `ListView`, just can't bind it when it's inside `ListView`.

WPF CODE:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Distributor">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="_distributor"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Why can't you just bind `ItemSource` of the combobox to your view model (assuming you are using an MVVM approach, which you should be)

Comment: not quite sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Could you please show some more context, e.g. the `ListView`, the binding to the `ComboBox` outside the `ListView` and the values you would like to bind, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi please try the next:

**Xaml code**

```
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="someBindingExampleSoHelpAttempt:UserModel">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
                                          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
                                          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"    
                                          TextSearch.TextPath="DepartmentName"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Departments}"    
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Department}"     
                                          DisplayMemberPath="DepartmentName" 
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="3"
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"     
                                          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"     
                                          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          TextSearch.TextPath="OfficeName"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding OfficesCollection}"    
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Office}"     
                                          DisplayMemberPath="OfficeName"      
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

**ViewModels and Models**

```
public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private DepartmentModel _selectedDepartment;
    private OfficeModel _selectedOffice;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Dal = new DataLayer();
        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
        Departments = new ObservableCollection<DepartmentModel>(Dal.GetAllDepartments());
        InitUsersCollection();
    }

    private void InitUsersCollection()
    {
        if(Departments == null) return;
        Departments.ToList().ForEach(model =>
        {
            model.Offices.ToList().ForEach(officeModel =>
            {
                if (officeModel.Users == null) return;
                officeModel.Users.ToList().ForEach(userModel => Users.Add(userModel));
            });
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DepartmentModel> Departments { get; set; }

    private DataLayer Dal { get; set; }

}

public class DataLayer
{
    public List<DepartmentModel> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        //pull and map your collection sources using your DB service
        //For example:
        return new List<DepartmentModel>
        {
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 1,
                DepartmentName = "A",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 1,
                        OfficeName = "AA",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "Avicenna", LastName = "Abu Ali Abdulloh Ibn-Sino"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Omar", LastName = "Khayyam"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "RAMBAM", LastName = "Moshe ben Maimon"}
                        })
                    },
                    new OfficeModel 
                    {

                        DepartmentId = 1, 
                        OfficeName = "AB", 
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "Leo", LastName = "Tolstoi"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Anton", LastName = "Chekhov"},
                        })},
                }
            },
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 2,
                DepartmentName = "B",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 2, OfficeName = "BA",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "B", LastName = "O"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "B", LastName = "N"},
                        }),
                    },
                    new OfficeModel
                    {
                        DepartmentId = 2, OfficeName = "BB",
                        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>(new List<UserModel>
                        {
                            new UserModel {Name = "John", LastName = "Walker"},
                            new UserModel {Name = "Gregory", LastName = "Rasputin"},
                        }),
                    },
                }
            },
            new DepartmentModel
            {
                DepartmentId = 3,
                DepartmentName = "C",
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeModel>
                {
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CA"},
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CB"},
                    new OfficeModel {DepartmentId = 3, OfficeName = "CC"}
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class OfficeModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private int _departmentModel;
    private string _officeName;
    private DepartmentModel _department;
    private ObservableCollection<UserModel> _users;

    public int DepartmentId
    {
        get { return _departmentModel; }
        set
        {
            _departmentModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DepartmentModel Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            _department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string OfficeName
    {
        get { return _officeName; }
        set
        {
            _officeName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(()=>Users);
        }
    }
}

public class DepartmentModel:BaseObservableObject
{

    private string _departmentName;

    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return _departmentName; }
        set
        {
            _departmentName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<OfficeModel> Offices { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _lastName;
    private DepartmentModel _department;
    private OfficeModel _office;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DepartmentModel Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            _department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(()=>OfficesCollection);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OfficeModel> OfficesCollection
    {
        get { return Department.Offices; }
    }

    public OfficeModel Office
    {
        get { return _office; }
        set
        {
            _office = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListView's holding control DataContext declaration in XAML**

```
    <!--This User Control Holds The ListView as one of it's Contents-->
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <someBindingExampleSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

**Useful MVVM links (google the mvvm there are a tones of information)**
 1. [WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).
 2. [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish).
 3. [Learn how to correctly implement the MVVM pattern following a set of simple steps](http://www.learnmvvm.com/).

Let me know if you need more help.

Regards.